# Is there any way I can automate API testing in Postman?

Tags: json, api, postman

Is there any way such that I can automate API testing in Postman?

I have a set of APIs and testing it manually takes a lot of time. It would be great if it is possible to give the input JSON in file so that it takes input from that file and test and give results whether its success or fail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of the following:

1. [Collection Runner](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/intro_to_collection_runs/)
2. [Monitors in Postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors/)
3. [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman)

*Explanation:*

1. With collection runner you can run a collection of your requests (API endpoints) all at one go and along with that you can write tests then it'll give you a result whether how many tests passed/failed.
   There are more advanced things you can do with collection runner such as creating an infinite collection run with the use of `postman.setNextRequest`
2. You can make use of Postman Monitors which is basically your collection is ran in the cloud at a scheduled time (every day / as per the schedule you specify) and then monitor reports are shown which will basically give you the performance metrics and test reports of your APIs.
3. You can use Newman which is the command line tool and you can integrate it with your test pipeline / there are multiple ways in which people use newman. You can also generate HTML reports etc.

You can reach out to [Postman Community](https://community.getpostman.com/latest) for more help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run Postman collections using `newman`.

`newman run mycollection.json`

For usage details check [this link](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/) out.