# How to schedule or automate postman run

Tags: postman

I have task to do eveyday 7pm and 7am .
Kind of toggle on/off services

Is there any way we can automate postman to run automatically

Comment: Also, this postman service has apigee proxy fronting for authorized token which further prefixed to put & Get operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way I can automate API testing in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940427/is-there-any-way-i-can-automate-api-testing-in-postman)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robotic process automation- Uipath 
Just download the studio(To code the automation) and the robot - (To carry out the automation)
https://www.uipath.com/